# How to set multi-value environment variables in Bamboo builds?

Tags: bamboo, finalbuilder

I am using Bamboo as my continuous integration server. I’ve defined my build projects using FinalBuilder (FB) and call the appropriate FB projects inside Bamboo using FB’s command line tool (FBCMD).

It seems that Bamboo runs commands in a pure environment without any environment variables defined. (despite what is mentioned in its spec !!!) So, many of my builds are failed due to the lack of INCLUDE variable used by VC++ compiler.

I’ve also tried the environment variables field of command configuration. But, only the first include path is taken into consideration and the rest is not considered at all.

Comment: Are you sure your plan is executed on the machine you expect it to? And user? I have not experienced the 'pure environment" issue ever. A possible quick fix is to use a 'script' task instead of 'command' - then you can set any variables you want to.

Comment: Yep ! I am sure. I have only one build machine and one user as well. This issues was found on Bamboo 3.x and I am not sure if it is resolved on new versions on not?